# Interface between form tag and anchor tag in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, perl, cgi

Hi I am a newbie to html and javascript . I have the following code of horizontal menu with some css style.

```
    <style>
      ul
    {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
     }
    a.a1
    {
    float:left;
    width:6em;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    background-color:purple;
    padding:0.2em 0.6em;
    border-right:1px solid white;
    }
     a.a1:hover {background-color:#ff3300;}
    li {display:inline;}
      </style>
     </head>

     <body>
     <ul>
    <li><a class="a1" href="process.pl">Precheck</a></li>
    <li><a class="a1" href="robostats.pl">Reboot</a></li>
    <li><a class="a1" href="get.pl">Get</a></li>
   <li><a class="a1" href="scen.pl">Scen</a></li>
    <li><a class="a1" href="start.pl">start</a></li>
   </ul>
   The form tag is as below
 <form action="#" id=sel method="post">

   <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 
  </form>
```

Now when i click on "Precheck" in the horizontal menu I want to get the checked list of form tag and run process.pl script . Please help me on how to get this.

Comment: Please be clear in your questions. Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/WmN5R/ for you. How can i help you with this ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen Please Run my code and see now

Answer (score 0):

You should add this code in your `process.pl` and the files you need `(robostats.pl, get.pl, scan.pl).`

```
$vehicle=$_POST['vehicle'];
```

Comment: yes this works . Actually i will execute step by step .process.pl, robostats.pl scen.pl etc . For suppose if i want to excute first scen.pl with the list of chekboxes. Will this work. I want a option kind of thing and should work for both step by step and independent

Comment: Yes. It will work, Then you should paste the code in all the required pages that want it to work.

Comment: i mean if the input of checkboxes is from previous perl program for eg . robostats.pl . i want to run in a different way or else i want to run the way as u gave the answer . Please help me with this . Did u get me ???

Comment: Yes you can do it easily by using SESSION ( reference link here  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp ).

Comment: If i get the input from previous program i am getting those checkboxes value as my $q = CGI->new; @scenario = $q->param('name'); ... else "do it as ur way " ....

Comment: and once i click precheck my entire horizontal menu is vanishing and processing . I want my horizontal menu also it should not vanish....

Comment: You should start the session by $_SESSION['vehicle']=$q; or param(name) that you use. And then you should set the condition if(isset($_SESSION['bike or your condition'])) { your action } else {your another action }

Comment: Here is the php sesssions reference link for you http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: hi .. can u show me the  $vehicle=$_POST['vehicle']; work . coz its not working here :(

Comment: You should use <form action="filename or parameter" id=sel method="post"> to see the effect.

Comment: its going to process.pl . But the value of the checkboxes is not posting

Comment: bhai . The value of checkboxes is not going into $vehicle . but since in href we gave process.pl it is going to that .pl file